# PDF reader with zoom

Tags: debian, pdf-reader, zoom

I'm working with largish PDFs (e.g. 17523x2383 dots @ 72dpi), where i need to zoom out (to see the overall picture and to navigate) and to zoom in (to read labels on the nodes).

The PDFs are simple graphs (generated from `gv`) containing mostly text, text-boxes and lines, andthe occasional thumbnail image. The only thing special about them is there size.

I don't think, that the graphics are complicated to render, e.g. using the [xdot.py](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py) program to visualize the `gv` graphs (before they are rendered into a PDF) is blindingly fast, so I can scroll and zoom arbitrarily in realtime.

Unfortunately, it seems that all all *PDF readers* (that I have tried) have problems with such formats.

Afaict, I require the the following features:
- fast renderer (so it can be used interactively)
- zoom in to `>100%` (ideally unlimited)
- zoom out to `<2%` (ideally unlimited)
- when zooming, keep focus
- minimal dependences (i'm running *xfce4*; i'd rather not pull in half of *kde* or *gnome* just to display a PDF)
- free software (FLOSS)

These are the readers that i've tried:

- `evince`: renders the complete page nicely (at a zoom-level `4.93%`), but refuses to zoom in to more than `41.47%`)
- `vprerex`: only has 6 fixed zoom-levels between `100%` and `400%`, thus not allowing me navigate.
- `mupdf`: limits zoom-out to `25%`; more importantly, I haven't found a way to keep a given point focused, when using the scroll-wheel to zoom-in, thus making it impossible to navigate the page.
- `firefox built-in PDF reader`: while it limits zoom-out with the mouse-wheel to `25%`, it also allows for a `zoom to page-width` which allows for an overall view of the image, and then to zoom in (until `1000%`) ata select spot. unfortunately, rendering at any size where the font is big enough to be readable (e.g. `70%` and above) makes the image very *blury*
- `atril` limits zoom-in to `50%`
- `qpdfviewer` loses focus when zooming; takes ages to render a new zoom level

So my question is: is there a free (as in *Free/Libre/OpenSource Software*) PDF reader (this rules out `Adobe PDF reader`) that allows for arbitrary and interactive zoom in/zoom out?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Almost all PDF readers can do what you require. Notable examples are Adobe PDF Reader (mentioned below) and Foxit Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not mentioned it: Adobe PDF Reader seems your way to go.
Not sure how you could have missed that. You can Zoom up to 6400%. I think that would be all you need.

Comment: i should have made it *more* clear that i'm really  looking for a  `Free/Libre/OpenSource` option - which rules out adobe acrobat reader.

Comment: Well it sure isn't open source but it's definitly free. Not sure why you would need an Open Source Reader but I can't help you out on that part I'm afraid. But since it's off Topic you might wanna Switch to the other board for that.

Comment: Adobe Reader is getting very long on the tooth -- last version dates from 20130426 -- over 6 1/2 years ago now. Are there any other PDF viewers with more zoom?